# how to calculate column sum in asp .net gridview without using footer row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` with one column showing cost. I would like to sum this cost and display as billing amount. upon `adding/deleting` a row billing amount should be `updated`.

I am using `asp .net c#`.

Comment: Do you want to show the sum in the first row or label or what exactly? AND PLEASE SHOW YOUR EFFORT..

Comment: I would like to store this in a variable and display it in a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it at `rowDataBound` event, where you will be able to access each `cell` at the row being bound at the moment and sum the values into a `variable`.

An Alternative way is to directly calculate the values from the `Database`

Comment: The value does not come from database. It is actually user input data so after each row is added i would like to sum the cost and display in a label above the grid.

Comment: so you are not saving anything in the database? even the user input? If so you can loop through the grid view row by row and use the "findControl()" method on each row to capture the input control you are using to get the user input, convert it to int or real or whatever numeric variable you are using, and sum them up

Comment: after editing your answer my reputation is increased by 2, so i am upvoting you.

Comment: It is not directly stored in database. I am maintaining shopping cart, once all the items are placed in cart and user clicks submit order only then the data is stored in database. Yes, i can loop through and sum the cost but that has to stored in a static variable and use this variable to deduct cost while row is deleted. I would like to avoid static variable. thanks a ton for the help

Comment: @user2536611, Thanks for your edit, it improved the answer, but you shouldn't upvote me for just accepting your edit, you should only upvote if you found the answer usefull :), Thanks

Comment: @HassanMokdad Welcome :) .hima will dicide usefulness. But you made my benefit, hence i made your benefit.

Comment: @user2536611 - its not that kind of game. If the information is helpful, upvote. If its detrimental, downvote. Voting based on anything else ruins the system for all users.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void txtUnitPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet dset3 = new DataSet();
        GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).Parent.Parent;
        TextBox qty = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtqty");
        TextBox qty1 = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtUnitPrice");
        string a = qty.Text;
        TextBox totalprice = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txttotal");
        totalprice.Text = (Double.Parse(qty1.Text) * Double.Parse(qty.Text)).ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Add detail to your answer or the output of the result to be more clear